# Magento 2 simple product details on parent page

Tags: php, magento, seo, magento2

I would need some help.

I need to create a custom thing on configurable products that is also seo friendly.

In my case I have a configurable product with 4 options which are simple products that are not visible. In case my customer clicks one of these options on page the info is updated and the url is also changed.

And here is the problem, in case the user reloads the page, it obviously responds with 404 since the product is not reachable.

I would need to then create the ability to redirect on the parent keeping the child url and then pre-select the infomation.

Adding that the pre-select is not a problem, I am using the X event to hook to the controller but I cannot in any way change the url.

Could you maybe help me or in case direct me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys I answered myself. To get around this problem I create rewrite urls at the prototto jump of my case history where the child fake url points to the parent